# Calculate the information amount (entropy) of a sentence

Tags: computer-science, information-theory

How I should calculate the entropy of a sentence of symbols for example "this is a string", should I use the Shannon's formula and use the probability of each symbol of the sentence depending on the table of probabilities of english language symbols and it's a too long operation, or just calculate the entropy of English language by Hartley's formula log2(27) and then the result multiply by the length of the sentence?

Comment: It depends on your goal.  What are you trying to accomplish with this measurement?

Comment: You need a model that determines a probability distribution over sentences. Are we selecting letters independently at random? Selecting words independently at random? Generating from a more sophisticated language model? This determines the probability of a given sentence, which in turn determines its information content.

Comment: The goal is just calculate the entropy of the sentence

Comment: Karl, I have no idea, just the question is that.